# How to add a single element to the web page using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am adding a single button to the end of ul tag using MutationObserver but I am getting infinite buttons at the end.

The following is the JavaScript code that will find the ul tag and append a single button at the end.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.classList.add('w-full');
        button.classList.add('bg-gray-50');
        button.classList.add('p-3');
        button.classList.add('dark:bg-white/5');
        button.classList.add('gap-3');
        button.classList.add('rounded-md');
        button.classList.add('hover:bg-gray-200');
        button.classList.add('dark:hover:bg-gray-900');
        button.classList.add('text-white');
        button.classList.add('cursor-pointer');
        button.classList.add('text-sm');
        button.innerText = "Code Generator";
        //button.onclick = showModal;

        //button.innerHTML = "Click me!";

        // Add an event listener to the button
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            alert("You clicked the button!");
        });
        document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(button);
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

It is working but adding multiple buttons and continue to add more buttons when scrolled down the page.

[image]

So I am not sure how to add only one instead of adding more and more buttons on page scroll. Any help will be highly appreciable how to stop the observer after adding the first button.